# Change SearchView default icon for BrowseFragment for Android TV applications?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

For Leanback `BrowseFragment`, by default there is a search view to the left of the screen. Is it a way to change the default icon of that `SearchOrbView` or hide it.

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*oIFbcdjYrIqxU55-B23tjA.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to change the icon then in you styles.xml

```
 <style name="NewSeachTheme" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="searchOrbViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchOrbView</item>
    <item name="defaultSearchColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomSearchOrbView" parent="Widget.Leanback.SearchOrbViewStyle">
    <item name="searchOrbIcon">add your drawable here</item>
    <item name="searchOrbIconColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Here the searchOrbIconColor is transparent because if your icon is small then the default icon color will be shown behind the search icon you use. 
Then add the new style "NewSeachTheme" to the Theme in manifest. 
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 6):

As stated by the documentation on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.html#setOnSearchClickedListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) if you don't call `setOnSearchClickedListener` the Search orb will be invisible:

> public void **setOnSearchClickedListener** (View.OnClickListener listener)
>
> Sets a click listener for the search affordance.
>
> The presence of a listener will change the visibility of the search
>   affordance in the fragment title. When set to non-null, the title will
>   contain an element that a user may click to begin a search.

If you want instead change the icon of the `SearchOrbView` you can do it editing your style:

```
<style name="Theme.Example.Leanback" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="searchOrbViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchOrbView</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomSearchOrbView" parent="Widget.Leanback.SearchOrbViewStyle">
    <item name="searchOrbIcon">@drawable/your_search_orb_icon</item>
</style>
```